# 3D reconstruction from a single 2D image on an uncalibrated camera?

Tags: computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

I'm very new to this space so I'm not sure if this question is obvious or not but I thought I would ask anyways.

I have been doing research into 3D reconstruction from a single 2D image for anatomical class specific objects (hands, faces, etc). from the papers I have read to perform 3D reconstruction on a single 2D image requires building a 3D Morphable Model. once 3DMM is built you can then match a 2D image to the Morphable Model by labeling landmarks onto the 2d image.

Is possible to perform this reconstruction on **uncalibrated cameras**?

The reason I am asking is that I would like to make an application that performs this type of 3D reconstruction from a mobile device (an iPhone for example) but having to perform camera calibration prior to taking a photo is something I would rather avoid if at all possible.

Thank you in advance for any information provided:)

Comment: Using only one camera you can only have an estimate (and not a good one), and even without calibration not sure how you may do that. Calibration must be done only once and stored in memory (unless optical zoom changes).

Comment: what if two cameras were used (i.e. stereo vision) instead of just one? (since most mobile devices come with two or more cameras today).

Comment: Of course! With two you have _stereo_ vision! You need a passive stereo vision algorithm to match the left and right points. You can do some experiments yourself [here for example](https://github.com/decadenza/SimpleStereo).

Comment: thank you very much for the help and source:) would the cameras still require calibration to be preformed?

Comment: Usually yes, although there are uncalibrated algorithms out there, they are mainly based on machine learning. Calibrating may be unpleasant but you only do it once. It's geometry, it works. Go and look on Google Scholar or ResearchGate.

Comment: There are programs like [MiDaS](https://huggingface.co/spaces/pytorch/MiDaS) that do "monocular depth estimation" from only one photo, but this is only a rough estimate instead of an accurate reconstruction.